# pymssql uninstalls anaconda when I do conda install

Tags: python, anaconda, package, pymssql

When I want to do a conda install of pymssql `conda install -c prometeia pymssql`
 it states that `The following packages will be REMOVED: anaconda: 5.2.0-py36_3`.
So how can I install pymssql within Anaconda without removing anaconda?

Comment: Can you please post the complete input and output for this command? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to first create and activate the virtual environment and then execute `conda install some_package`.